# C# WinForms - TreeView, Context Menu

Tags: winforms, treeview, contextmenu

Suppose I am using a context menu to add child nodes to a treeview control.

(1) I am right-clicking on the node

(2)context menu pop up

(3)then I click "Add" menu item

(4)a dialogBox opens up

(5) I input the name in that DialogBox and press OK

(6) A new Node is created.

How can I get the reference of the current Node when I am clicking on the context menu item?

I need this coz the parent object is stored in the Tag property of the current node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you handle [`TreeNodeMouseClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemouseclick%28VS.85%29.aspx), then your `TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler` will be passed a `TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs` argument.

TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs.Node will be the TreeNode reference you want. See the [`TreeNodeMouseClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemouseclick%28VS.85%29.aspx) docs for an example similar to:

```
void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender,  
    TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode theTreeNodeIWant = e.Node

}
```

If you need to, you can store a reference in a member variable so another method can access it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the mouse position from

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
```

Save this before showing the context menu.

Then use the method on the Treeview containing your items

```
GetChildAtPoint(Point)
```

and add a child below that.